# DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor without having to create ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-async

After upgrading Spring versions, I noticed that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` was null inside an `AuditorAware` type used as part of an `@Async` method.

Following some answers, here, I added these to my Spring Boot Application class: ...

```
@Bean
public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
    return executor;
}

@Bean 
public DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor) { 
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor); 
}
```

...And everything runs great!

However, given that the Async methods were already being executed asynchronously without the creation of a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` Bean, shouldn't I be able to `@Autowired` that Bean/Component for my `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor`, instead of having to create a new `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`?

Comment: this is impossible for us to answer since we have no idea what your previous implementation looked like. Please provide a working example that runs with your previous code, and an example with your new code. You can use git to supply us the examples.